# how to disable to select one or many option from dropdown list in cakephp?

Tags: php, jquery, html, cakephp

I want to disable some options from dropdown list, i have an array like that

```
  array(
'all' => 'ALL',
'skip1' => 'User Define Groups:',
(int) 43 => '--Usii Group2',
(int) 105 => '--Usii Mailing [ mailing list]',
(int) 106 => '--test [ mailing list]',
'skip2' => 'Dynamic Define Groups:'


i want to disable value of skip1 and skip2, if user click on skip1 and skip2 value it can't be select in dropdown list, this is my view file     


    echo $this->FormManager->input('view',array('label'=>'View ','type'=>'select','options'=>$viewGroup,'default'=>$default));
```

any one can help to do this, it will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should disable options from client side, i.e from Jquery something like this

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option value="all">ALL/option>
    <option value="skip1">User Define Groups:</option>
    <option value="43 ">--Usii Group2</option>
    <option value="105">--Usii Mailing [ mailing list]</option>
    <option value="106">--test [ mailing list]</option>
    <option value="skip2">'Dynamic Define Groups:</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('option[value=skip1]').prop('disabled', true);
$('option[value=skip2]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement an answer from Moyed Ansari:
You can use .attr jquery function.

```
$('option[value=skip1]').attr('disabled', true);
$('option[value=skip2]').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of arrays.

```
$values = array(
  'all' => 'all',
  'skip1' => array(
    5 => 'ex',
    6 => 'ex',
    7 => 'ex',
  ),
  'skip2' => array(
    5 => 'ex',
    6 => 'ex',
    7 => 'ex',
  )
)
```

See here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::select

Answer (score 0):

Try with re-arrange the array by following way:

```
 array(
      'all' => 'ALL',
      'skip1' => array(
           'name' => 'User Define Groups:',
           'value' => 'skip1',
           'disabled' => true
      )
      (int) 43 => '--Usii Group2',
      (int) 105 => '--Usii Mailing [ mailing list]',
      (int) 106 => '--test [ mailing list]',
      'skip2' => (
           'name' => 'Dynamic Define Groups:'
           'value' => 'skip2',
           'disabled' => true
      )
 )
```

Or you can simply try this on your view :

```
echo $this->FormManager->input('view',array('label'=>'View ','type'=>'select','options'=>$viewGroup,'default'=>$default, 'disabled'=>array('skip1','skip2')));
```

Both of those do not require any JavaScript or jQuery.